# Are queries sent by same connection executed paralleled?

Tags: rethinkdb

> Is queries with same connection executed  paralleled ?
>
> Why or why not ?

If queries are executed paralleled, client can use just one non-blocking connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no (for now).

Currently there is the guarantee is that if you send a write, then a read (without waiting for the write to be acknowledge), you are sure that the read will see the write (if the write was successful).

This may or may not be kept in the future though.

Also connections are not thread safe. With Node, you can just easily share the same connection, but in Python/Ruby/etc, this may lead to errors